# Apply the same code in multiple dataframes at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a block of code that works fine for one dataframe, however, I have a list of 23 dataframes that I would like to apply the same code.

I tried to make a list of all dataframes and then through a for loop apply the code to each dataframe but I am getting length error messages.

Here is the block of code:

```
city_arr=[]
county_arr=[]
town_arr=[]
municipality_arr=[]
state_arr=[]
country_arr=[]

for i in range(len(df)):
  if 'address' in df['address'][i].raw:
    address = df['address'][i].raw.get("address", None)
    city = address.get('city', '') 
    town = address.get('town', '') 
    municipality = address.get('municipality', '')
    county = address.get('county','') 
    state = address.get('state','') 
    country = address.get('country','') 
    
    city_arr.append(city)
    state_arr.append(state)
    town_arr.append(town)
    municipality_arr.append(municipality)
    country_arr.append(country)
    county_arr.append(county)

df['city'] = city_arr
df['county'] = county_arr
df['town'] = town_arr
df['municipality'] = municipality_arr
df['state'] = state_arr
df['country'] = country_arr
```

Comment: Make it into a function that takes the dataframe as an argument. Then you can just call the function in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def my_func(df):
    """All the code in your example"""
    return(df)

for dataframe in dataframes:
    dataframe = my_func(dataframe)
```

If you use a function in this way you should not have the problem with length. This problem is most likely occurring because your dataframes are of different length and you are appending columns that are different in size to the dataframe in question.